# React Project not deploying on GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, github, github-pages

When I try and deploy my app to GitHub Pages, all I see is this page.:
[image]

My actual project works on localhost, but for some reason I can't get it to display on GitHub Pages. To my `package.json` I've added `"homepage": "https://username.github.io/my-site"`, and my scripts look like this:

```
    "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

The "username" in the homepage url is my actual GitHub username. Am I doing something wrong here? I think this is what the official GitHub tutorial suggested to do, unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Probably, you need to configure the [sources folder](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch) to point the pages to your build instead of readme.

Answer (score 0):

## Creating `build` folder

1. Run `npm build` to create production build of your website. A `build` folder containing the final version of your website will be created.
2. Push this folder to Github.

Everytime you make a change to your code, you will have to generate the `build` folder again for the changes to be reflected on Github Pages.

## Configuring `package.json`

In your `package.json`, you need to specify the `homepage` attribute:

```js
"homepage": "https://username.github.io/my-repository/build"
```

If your package.json file is located in some sub-folder of your repository instead of root, then your homepage attribute must be modified accordingly:

```js
"homepage": "https://username.github.io/my-repository/some-folder/build"
```

Notice that the homepage is pointing to the `build` folder.

Your website will be available at `https://username.github.io/my-repository/build`.